# Running Blazor WASM on Internet Explorer just shows "Loading.." instead of a meaningful error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, blazor, blazor-webassembly

We've deployed a Blazor WASM app in an org that has access to multiple browsers however the default (for now) happens to be IE 11 which doesn't support WASM.

The issue is the confusion when clicking URLs from notification emails (taking the user to the Blazor app), the user ends up in IE 11 with "Loading.." on the top left corner of the screen. Stays like that without any meaningful feedback.

I tried searching for this "Loading.." message in the source without success, is there a way to show something more meaningful to the user?

e.g. "Loading.. (Notice: this app is not compatible with Internet Explorer)"

Comment: "URLs from notification emails" - where are they pointing?  To your Blazxor app?

Comment: You could also change your strategy. Blazor Server Hosted does support IE11.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes URLs to the app.

Comment: @PaulSinnema too late for that :D but yes as an intranet app with 100 users only, a Blazor server-side app would have been a better option. Luckily IE is slowly phasing out so trying to survive until then.

Comment: @WaleedAlHarthi I'm also very pleased getting rid of IE11 finally.

Comment: @WaleedAlHarthi B.T.W. it doesn't seem to be too hard to do. Several posts on the web about that subject. Depends on your application of course. There might be blocking issues in your project but it worth investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading message is in your `index.html` - and you can change it to whatever you like. You can also advise the org to [configure Internet Explorer mode in Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies)

`index.html`

```html
<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>
```